# Program exiting after Gst.init(None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am writing a GUI program which should get live video from Raspberry Pi's camera using GStreamer 1.6.2 and Python 3.4. BTW, now I am complitely at the begining..

Following tutorials I've written this...:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gst, GObject

print(0)
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
print(1)
```

After printing 0 program waits for ~10sec and stopping with no output. Same in running and debuging mode.

I can't find any examples of such situation and solutions. What's the problem?

Comment: For me, your code prints 0 and, after about a second, 1, and then exits.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed that by reinstalling Python and PyGObject.